# Dragging a popup modal extender inside an usercontrol

Tags: asp.net, user-controls, ajaxcontroltoolkit, drag, modalpopupextender

I'm trying to use a modal popup extender.
But I have a problem when using it inside an userControl.
I put the drag property true, and PopupDragHandleControlID but I can't drag the popup.

It seams that this problem happens only when I use the popup modal extender inside the userControl.
If I use it inside an aspx page, then it is OK.
Please can you help me how to deal with this problem?

Here is the code that I use in my user control:

```
       <asp:LinkButton ID="lnk" runat="server" Text="Rezervo"></asp:LinkButton>
        <ajax:ModalPopupExtender ID="ModalPopupExtender1" BackgroundCssClass="ModalPopupBG"
            runat="server" CancelControlID="btnCancel" OkControlID="btnOkay" TargetControlID="lnk"
            PopupControlID="pnlBooking" Drag="true" PopupDragHandleControlID="PopupHeader">
        </ajax:ModalPopupExtender>
        <div id="pnlBooking" style="display: none;" class="popupConfirmation">
            <div class="popup_Container">
                <div class="popup_Titlebar" id="PopupHeader">
                    <div class="TitlebarLeft">
                        Rezervo</div>
                    <div class="TitlebarRight">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="popup_Body">
                </div>
                <div class="popup_Buttons">
                    <input id="btnOkay" value="Done" type="button" />
                    <input id="btnCancel" value="Cancel" type="button" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```